# Tor$(A) \ne 0$ in free group.

Tags: group-theory

Consider $G = \mathbb{Z}_{2} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$. It's free group and it's subgroup generating by $(1,1)$ is also free group. But we know that $A - $ free if and only if when $Tor(A) = 0$. But $Tor(A') \ne 0$ ,so where I go wrong ?

Comment: What is $A$ and $A'$?

Comment: What makes you think $G$ is free?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume $\mathbb{Z}_2$ means the cyclic group of two elements?

$\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ is not a free group. It is not a free abelian group either.

Answer (score 0):

$G$ is not free.  $G$ has, for example, the (minimally generated) presentation
$$  \langle a,b \mid 2a \rangle  $$
(Free groups are "relation-free groups".)

Comment: Somewhat more needs to be argued. E.g. $\langle a, b \mid  a \rangle$ is a presentation that has a nontrivial relation in it, but it still presents a free group, so simply having a presentation with a relation in it isn't enough to prove something isn't free.

Comment: @Hurkyl : Not to be too pointy, but the argument in your answer is even less complete.

Comment: I *didn't* give an argument $G$ isn't free. (I didn't feel the need to since the OP seems to have already stated a proof, and is simply having trouble accepting the result) I'm only commenting since the argument given isn't actually a valid one that the OP could try applying to other problems they face in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about abelian group and “free” means “free abelian”.

1. A free abelian group is torsionfree, being isomorphic to a direct sum of copies of $\mathbb{Z}$.
2. Therefore $\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}$ is not free.
3. An abelian group can be torsionfree but not free, for instance $\mathbb{Q}$.